# Magento: How to save/overwrite additional data during checkout?

Tags: magento

Is there any possibility to save/overwrite some individual fields during the customization of a bundled product? Because there is no possibility to add individual options to a bundled product with a dynamic price, I need to know how the user can add some additional information (like a text for an engraving, or image upload) during the order process of a bundle?!

Therefore I also can´t use attributes, as I read, because they are fixed for all products and couldn't be manipulated for an order item separately...

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This question could easily lead to a 10+ hour project.  So, fyi, you probably are not going to find some easy answer here.

Answer (score -1):

You have got catalog price rules and shopping cart price rules feature in magento. You can relate banners as well for rules. I hope you can try to achieve your requirement by using this feature if my understanding of the question is right.